# How can i set a pagination in detailed page

Tags: paging

How can i set a pagination in detailed pages? for example i have 10 pages in common blogs and the main page contain only the description about the content.When we click on the title of the page or readmore then it will displaying the detail of specified content here i want to set the pager how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is one of Drupal's most commonly used modules, [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). Views lets you:

- Select any content you want of your choice (in your case blog posts)
- Show only the fields you want on that content (in your case a title link & description).
- Display it in a form of your choice (in your case a dedicated page with a pager).

You shouldn't have any trouble finding tutorials on Views. For example, here is [one from Acquia](https://www.acquia.com/blog/totally-beginner-tutorial-views-drupal-7).